# How does gifting work on Marvel Contest of the Champions?

Tags: marvel-contest-champions

1. How can the gifting badge be acquired? As far as I know, the only way is by making an in-app purchase of a pack that contains that badge.
2. To whom can I send gifts? Any players? friends? alliance members?
3. What items can I send? Can I send champions? Can I send crystals? Can I send boosts?
4. Does it cost anything to send items? (per transaction, ignoring the cost of the gifting badge itself)

Answer (score 1):

1. Can't be earned, only bought.
2. Players on your friends list.
3. Items you buy.
4. Costs to purchase the items you gift.

Comment: So, for item 3, no champions, only items, any items, including every type of crystal? and for item 4, the cost of transaction is based on the item you are sending? is that what you mean?